# Is it possible to use Howler.js to play a sound off a remote server?

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, web-audio-api, howler.js

Using basic JavaScript, it is possible to play an .mp3 off a remote server (as opposed to loading a file off the same server where the code is running), as seen in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gD4Dr/35/).

```
var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');

audioElement.setAttribute('src', 'http://www.uscis.gov/files/nativedocuments/Track%2093.mp3');
audioElement.setAttribute('autoplay', 'autoplay');

audioElement.addEventListener("load", function() {
    audioElement.play();
}, true);
```

Is the same thing possible with [Howler.js](https://github.com/goldfire/howler.js/tree/2.0)? I haven't been able to accomplish it.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation says that the `urls` array will take any URL or base64 encoded URI. So something like this should work:

```
var sound = new Howl({
    urls: ['http://www.uscis.gov/files/nativedocuments/Track%2093.mp3']
}).play();
```

Note, however, that the mp3 format is not supported in all browsers: [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=mp3)

---

**EDIT**: You may run into CORS problems (Same Origin Policy).

**Edit 2**: As @JamesSimpson points out in the comments, the html5 audio fallback should prevent any issues with CORS.

Comment: This is correct; however, even if the correct CORS headers aren't present. howler.js will automatically fall back to hTML5 Audio, which doesn't have issues with CORS and will still play.

Comment: Does this stream the audio data or does it download the file first? I have larger audio files which would take too long to download entirely.